# Test if Pandas column is datetime type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to `fillna` per column with a suitable variable. My goal is to try find the column type at the highest level of generality: basically, at the moment it is either numeric (int/float), string, or pandas `Timestamp`. I understand that I can detect numeric or string using `numpy.issubdtype` and the [type hierarchy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html), but I haven't found a way to detect `Timestamp`. My solution uses `iloc[0]` and `isinstance`, but is there something better? Here is my code, roughly:

```
for col in df:
    if np.issubdtype(dataframe[col].dtype, np.number):
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(-1)
    elif isinstance(dataframe[col].iloc[0], pd.datetime):
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna('NaN')
    return (dataframe.fillna(na_var)
```

(Note that I can't use `df.loc[0, col]` because my index doesn't always contain 0.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form me, `np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.datetime64)` does what you want.

So taking everything together, we have:

```
def df_fillna(df):
    for col in df:
        if np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.number):
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(-1)
        elif np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.datetime64):
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))
        else:
            df[col] = df[col].fillna('NaN')
        return df
```

An example. Input:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame()
df_test['dates'] = [pd.to_datetime("2009-7-23"), pd.to_datetime("2011-7-7"), pd.NaT]
df_test = df_fillna(df_test)
```

Output:

```
       dates
0 2009-07-23
1 2011-07-07
2 1900-01-01
```

Comment: Ah, so simple, can't believe I missed it. Thanks!